# FlowDefinition Scope issue in JBoss 7.1 - Migration to JSF 2.2.1

Tags: jsf, jboss, jsf-2.2, weld, flow-scope

I did the instruction from this website ([JSF 2.2 in JBoss 7.1.1 Final](https://community.jboss.org/thread/203257)). After I overcome the problem posted :

- [ClassNotFoundException for JSTL jar when I try to migrate JBoss 7.1 application to JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300722/jboss-7-1-migration-to-jsf-2-2)

I get new issue.

`No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition`

Stack Trace :

```
14:57:33,400 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-8) Critical error during deployment: : org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveExceptio
n: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:607) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:2012-04-29 10:45]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.loadFlows(ApplicationAssociate.java:322) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:302) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108) [jsf-api-2.2.1.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2163) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:296) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:288) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739) [jsf-api-2.2.1.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:691) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:253) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]

14:57:33,416 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jsf-cdi]] (MSC service thread 1-8) Exception sending context initialized event to listener i
nstance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type
 javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:607) [weld-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:2012-04-29 10:45]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.loadFlows(ApplicationAssociate.java:322) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:302) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108) [jsf-api-2.2.1.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2163) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:296) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:288) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739) [jsf-api-2.2.1.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:691) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:253) [jsf-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
```

I tried to change `weld-core` module in `JBoss 7` with the following jar fils.

```
weld-core-1.1.8.Final.jar
weld-core-2.1.1.Final.jar
```

It does not effect, error is the same. How can I resolve it?

Comment: AFAIK, you need JBoss 8 to get JSF 2.2 fully working.

Comment: @Gimby: Out the box, yes. But JSF 2.2 is (should be) backwards compatible with Java EE 6. CycDemo: Mojarra 2.2.1 is half a year old already. It's currently at 2.2.5. Give it a try first. Then we can exclude old Mojarra bugs from being the cause.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that JBoss EAP 7 (and I assume Wildfly 10) also needs is a `beans.xml` file in the war project `WEB-INF` directory.

We have a number of EAR projects, with an EJB project containing the java code. It used to be that the `beans.xml` in this EJB project was sufficient to have JSF use CDI scopes, but with EAP 7 / JSF 2.2 this isn't enough anymore and the `war` project itself also needs this marker file.

I assume this is more standard compliant, but can lead to interesting bug chases if you don't realize this.